# Handle on-off switch with Selenium / java

Tags: selenium, xpath

I can neither recognize the on-off switch nor get its current value (On / Off).

Please help to have a look

- try using xpath = "//span[@class='onoffswitch-inner' and contains(@id,'aui')]" but it doesn't help to recognize this button
- "id" is a dynamic one, it will be changed once loading the page

Code:

```
<li id="aui_3_4_0_1_1099">
<div id="aui_3_4_0_1_1098" class="onoffswitch">
<input id="notificationActive" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked="checked" name="notificationActive"></input>
<label id="aui_3_4_0_1_1097" class="onoffswitch-label" for="notificationActive">
<span id="aui_3_4_0_1_1096" class="onoffswitch-inner">
::before
::after
</span>
<span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</div>
</li>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried css selector to find element?

Comment: I did try but it doesn't help

Comment: Any suggestion for this? Thanks.